# I'm trying to rewrite a program that echoes what the user typed a line a time everytime the ENTER key is pressed

Tags: assembly, lc3

The original program just took last thing character the user typed and displayed it on the console. I'm trying to expand it so that it displays a line a time by waiting for the user to press ENTER. 
for example if the user types in:
 "hello World"
then it waits for the user to press enter and displays it on the console.

But when I run it it doesn't display anything.

current code:

```
.ORIG x3000
LEA    R3, MEM
LD R2, LINE
LOOP LDI R0, KBSR ; Load the value of the KBSR into R0
  BRzp LOOP ; If KBSR[15] = 0, no key has been pressed
  LDI R0, KBDR ; Copy the waiting character from the KBDR to R0
  LDI R3, KBDR ; copy the wating character into R3

LOOP2 LDI R1, DSR ; Load the value of the DSR into R1
  BRzp LOOP2 ; If DSR[15] = 0, the display is not ready
  ADD R2, R0, #-10 ; checks to see if Enter key was pressed
  BRz display : if so go to display characters
  BRnp LOOP
display  STI R3, DDR ; Copy the character in R0 to the Data display register
  ADD R3, R3, #1 ; update storatge location.
HALT
DSR .FILL xFE04
DDR .FILL xFE06
KBSR .FILL xFE00
KBDR .FILL xFE02
MEM .BLKW 10 
LINE .fill #10
.END
```

code I was trying to expand from:

```
.ORIG x3000
LOOP LDI R0, KBSR ; Load the value of the KBSR into R0
  BRzp LOOP ; If KBSR[15] = 0, no key has been pressed
  LDI R0, KBDR ; Copy the waiting character from the KBDR to R0
LOOP2 LDI R1, DSR ; Load the value of the DSR into R1
  BRzp LOOP2 ; If DSR[15] = 0, the display is not ready
  STI R0, DDR ; Copy the character in R0 to the DDR
  BRnzp LOOP
HALT
DSR .FILL xFE04
DDR .FILL xFE06
KBSR .FILL xFE00
KBDR .FILL xFE02
.END
```

edit 1 8/3/15 6.21pm:
So I'm getting these weird symbols now.
I;m not sure if the characters are going in the memory locations.
I subtract from R3 to loop back that way I can display all the characters in that register but I'm getting these weird symbols and I don't know where their from.
[Weird symbols on console](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/uploads/monthly_08_2015/post-672703-143865272149.jpg)

new code:

```
.ORIG x3000
  LD R2, LINE
LOOP4  LEA R3, MEM 
LOOP  LDI R0, KBSR ; Load the value of the KBSR into R0
  BRzp LOOP ; If KBSR[15] = 0, no key has been pressed
  LDI R0, KBDR ; Copy the waiting character from the KBDR to R0
  STR R0, R3, #0; copy the wating character into R3

LOOP2 LDI R1, DSR ; Load the value of the DSR into R1
  BRzp LOOP2 ; If DSR[15] = 0, the display is not ready
  ADD R3, R3, #1 ; update storage location
  ADD R2, R0, #-10 ;checks for return key
  BRz loop3
  BRnp LOOP

loop3 STI R3, DDR ; Copy the character in R3 to the Data display register
  ADD R3, R3, #-1
  BRP loop3
  BRz LOOP4


HALT
DSR .FILL xFE04
DDR .FILL xFE06
KBSR .FILL xFE00
KBDR .FILL xFE02
MEM .BLKW 64 
LINE .fill #10
.END
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the entered characters into a buffer, and loop through the buffer when you want to display them.  What is being "displayed" by your code is the ENTER key.